# Initiate polipay payment from form details using ajax with headers to rest api

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, paypal

Can someone please help me with this code to initiate a payment transaction with polipay - http://www.polipaymentdeveloper.com/initiate

I know I've got truckloads of dumb things I'm doing in this code which I'm not too worried about as long as it works in the end and we can sort the main issues. As in i'm not worried about little code optimizations.

This is part of a php page that is essentially just a processing page to update the database from a user submitted form and then forward the details to payment processors. I have another form setup that does PayPal and it works fine as I can use form actions because PayPal doesn't require http authentication headers. I initially had this form setup much the same as my PayPal one but it just came up with a request for username and password as soon as it was submitted - obviously not ideal.

```
<form name="poli_form" id="poli_form" >
    <!-- POLi Pay Configuration -->
    <input type="hidden" name="auth" value="<?php echo base64_encode(get_option( 'cts_polipay_merchant_code' ) . ":" . get_option( 'cts_polipay_authentication_code' ));?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="homeurl" value="<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="success" value="<?php echo the_permalink(get_option( 'cts_return_page' ));?>?transid=<?=$lastid;?>&payment_nonce=<?=$nonce;?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel" value="<?php echo the_permalink(get_option( 'cts_cancel_page' ));?>?transid=<?=$lastid;?>&payment_nonce=<?=$nonce;?>">
    <!-- Sponsor Information -->
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<?php echo sanitize_text_field($_POST['amount']);?>&name=<?php echo sanitize_text_field($_POST['name']['first']).' '.sanitize_text_field($_POST['name']['last']);?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo sanitize_text_field($_POST['amount']);?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="<?php echo sanitize_text_field($_POST['item_number']);?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="merchantdata" value="<?php echo sanitize_text_field($_POST['item_number']);?>~<?php echo sanitize_text_field($_POST['amount']);?>&name=<?php echo sanitize_text_field($_POST['name']['first']).' '.sanitize_text_field($_POST['name']['last']);?>~">
    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'process_payment', 'payment_nonce' ); ?>
</form>

<script>
window.onload = myFunction(){
var homeurlValue = $("#homeurl").val();
var successValue = $("#success").val();
var cancelValue = $("#cancel").val();
var item_nameValue = $("#item_name").val();
var amountValue = $("#amount").val();
var item_numberValue = $("#item_number").val();
var merchantdataValue = $("#merchantdata").val();
var auth = $("#auth").val();
$.ajax({
        type : 'POST',

        url : "https://poliapi.apac.paywithpoli.com/api/v2/Transaction/Initiate",
        //Add the request header
        headers : {
            Authorization : 'Basic ' + auth
        },
        contentType : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        //Add form data
        data : {homeurl: homeurlValue, success: successValue, cancel: cancelValue, item_name: item_nameValue, amount: amountValue, item_number: item_numberValue, merchantdata: merchantdataValue},
        success : function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error : function(xhr, status, error) {
            var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
            console.log(err);                   
        }
    }); //End of Ajax
 }   // End of myFucntion
</script>
```